Weierstrass' M-test and convergence of series
I came across with the following proof about the convergence of Dirichlet L-series but I have troubles understanding it:
Let $\delta >0$ and $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ satisfy $|f(n)|\leq n^{o(1)}$. Then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)n^{-s}$ converges absolutely to an analytic function for $\Re (s)\geq 1$, and uniformly absolutely on $\Re (s)\geq 1+\delta$.
The proof goes like this: Since $|f(n)|\leq n^{o(1)}$, there is an $N_0(\delta)$ such that $|f(n)|\leq n^{\delta/2}$ for $n\geq N_0$. If $\Re (s)\geq 1+\delta$, then for $N_2\geq N_1\geq N_0(\delta)$ we have
$$\sum_{n=N_1}^{N_2}\left| \frac{f(n)}{n^s} \right| \leq \sum_{n=N_1}^{N_2} \frac{n^{\delta/2}}{n^{\Re(s)}} \leq \int_{N_1-1}^{N_2}\frac{dt}{t^{1+\delta/2}}\leq \frac{2}{\delta(N_1-1)^{\delta/2}}$$.
For fixed $\delta>0$, this tends to $0$ as $N_1\rightarrow \infty$. Thus the series converges uniformly absolutely in the region $\Re (s) \geq 1+\delta$. Since $\delta$ is arbitrary, and the partial sums are clearly analytic, this gives the result. Q.E.D.
My question is, why it is ok to quote Weierstrass M-test when we let $N_1\rightarrow \infty$? We are trying to prove that the series $\sum_{n=N_1}^{N_2} \frac{n^{\delta/2}}{n^{\Re(s)}}$ converges as $N_2 \rightarrow \infty$. I understand that as $N_1\rightarrow \infty$, this forces $N_2\rightarrow \infty$ too, but doesn't that only "shift the summing interval"? So in short, when we try to prove $\sum_{n=N_1}^{\infty}$ converges (as a series of numbers), is it the same as proving $\sum_{n=N_1}^{N_2}$ converges as $N_1\rightarrow \infty$?
Another minor question is, is there any reason to choose $N_1-1$ instead of $N_1$?
Thank you so much for your help.

A series is uniformly convergent if it is uniformly Cauchy.
